# How to use Elasticsearch's scripted metric aggregations with Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'm trying to display an [elasticsearch scripted aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) in grafana.
I can't figure out where to setup my aggregation script in the grafana UI

**Elasticsearch aggregation**

```
{
  "scripted_metric": {
    "init_script": "_agg['transactions'] = []",
    "map_script": "if (doc['type'].value == \"sale\") { _agg.transactions.add(doc['amount'].value) } else { _agg.transactions.add(-1 * doc['amount'].value) }",
    "combine_script": "profit = 0; for (t in _agg.transactions) { profit += t }; return profit",
    "reduce_script": "profit = 0; for (a in _aggs) { profit += a }; return profit"
  }
}
```

**Grafana UI**

[image: metrics UI]

Comment: Not implemented as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once upon a time it was possible to toggle the query formulation mode for elasticsearch, similar to what is available for Graphite.  Sadly, this functionality  has been removed, but there is a fairly popular feature request to bring it back.  You can peruse the current state of the issue here: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/5428